# gunicorn does not start after boot

Tags: linux, django, web-services, nginx, gunicorn

I'm running a Debian web server with nginx and gunicorn running a django app. I've got everything up and running just fine but after rebooting the server I get a 502 bad gateway error. I've traced the issue back to gunicorn being inactive after the reboot. If I start the service the problem is fixed until I reboot the server again.

Starting the service:

```
systemctl start gunicorn.service
```

After the reboot here is my gunicorn service status:

```
{username}@instance-3:~$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Contents of my /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User={username}
Group={username}
WorkingDirectory=/home/{username}/web/{projname}
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn {projname}.wsgi:application
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi.user.target
```

Any ideas to figure out why the gunicorn service isn't starting after reboot?

Edit:

Could the issue be that the gunicorn.conf has a different dir in chdir and the exec than the working directory?

```
{username}@instance-3:~$ cat /etc/init/gunicorn.conf 
cription "Gunicorn application server handling {projname}"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid {username}
setgid {username}
chdir /home/data-reporting/draco_reporting

exec {projname}/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/{username}/data-reporting/{projname}/{projname}.sock {projname}.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a small typo in your `gunicorn.service` file. Change to:

```
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also, you may want to change to:

```
Restart=always
```

Comment: Edit: I re-ran `systemctl enable gunicorn.service` after fixing the typo and now it works as it should. Thanks!

Comment: not working, I already have my file in this way

Comment: Also make sure to enable it after modifying. "sudo systemctl enable gunicorn" Unless it won't auto start. You can check the status using "systemctl status gunicorn"

Answer (score 0):

I made old school crontab and the problem was solved.

```
crontab -e
```

and then

```
@reboot sudo systemctl restart nginx && sudo systemctl restart gunicorn.service
```

[image]

and just save crontab.