# gunicorn does not start after reboot

Tags: gunicorn

The advice given in [gunicorn does not start after boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43857549/gunicorn-does-not-start-after-boot)
does not solve my similar problem.

I'm using ubuntu server 20.04.1

my unit file:  /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn Web Server as Unit Service Systemd - slimzulu.hopto.me
After=network.target

[Service]
User=nols
Group=nols
WorkingDirectory=/home/nols/fastapi
Environment="PATH=/home/nols/fastapi/env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/nols/fastapi/env/bin/gunicorn --config /home/nols/fastapi/gunicorn.py main:app
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To activate the gunicorn.service

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.service
sudo systemctl start gunicorn.service
```

The status of gunicorn.service after boot (sudo systemctl status gunicorn.service
)

```
● gunicorn.service - Gunicorn Web Server as Unit Service Systemd - slimzulu.hopto.me
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-10-20 14:13:26 UTC; 3min 24s ago
    Process: 681 ExecStart=/home/nols/fastapi/env/bin/gunicorn --config /home/nols/fastapi/gunicorn.py main:app (code=exited, status=3)
   Main PID: 681 (code=exited, status=3)

Oct 20 14:12:52 ubuntuvirtual systemd[1]: Started Gunicorn Web Server as Unit Service Systemd - slimzulu.hopto.me.
Oct 20 14:13:26 ubuntuvirtual systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Oct 20 14:13:26 ubuntuvirtual systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

~

Any ideas to figure out why the gunicorn service isn't starting after reboot?